# graph of $z=2x+y$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The usual technique using traces where one variable is set to 0 does not seem to work here since I get all 0's and so where do the intersections meet?

I looked in my calc. book and the technique they use they drop 0 in two variables at a time and get the intersection of the three points where each point is gotten by setting the other two variables 0.  I get all 0's in this case too so that does not help either. Can someone help me graph this? My goal is to sketch the level curves to this equation but I must first sketch z= 2x + y. Then I can set z = 0 , 1 and so forth and the plane for each of the equations should intersect the graph of z=2x + y. I believe.     Thank you !!

Comment: Let's be clear about several things. 1. This is not calculus; it's just three dimensional analytic geometry. 2. The method of traces does work; in the $xy$ plane when $z=0$ you get the line $y=-2x$, etc. 3. Your equation gives a plane through the origin with normal vector $(2,1,-1)$.

Comment: This is just a plane through the origin for goodness sake! You can find the normal as @symplectomorphic suggests. For more advanced work that is the recommended approach. Or just note a couple of other obvious points in the plane. Remember a plane is defined by 3 points (provided they are not collinear).

Comment: The level curves are like the contour lines on a topographical map showing the elevation of the surface. In this example all the contour lines will be straight lines parallel to each other. Pick a set of 'elevations,' that is, values of $z$ and draw the corresponding contour lines. e.g $z=-2,-1,0,1,2$, etc. That should indicate that the graph is a plane.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a rectangular graph through the origin,as dictated by the level curves 2x + y= 0 , 2x-z =0 and y-z =0. The resulting surface should look like this:

[image]